# Using a/ aille after quoi que ce soit

Tags: subjonctif

I want to pose a question, either the subjuntive or past work:

Avait-il quoi que ce soit dans le rapport que vous a/ aille surpris?

Is this okay?

Comment: @LPH: Que signifie le tag « pronom complexe »?

Comment: @Toto et al On trouve le terme dans l'article que je fournis, à sont tout début; il n'est pas expliqué  mais il en existe une sorte élémentaire (tels que « auxquels ou à qui ») qui sont appelés ainsi parce qu'ils sont constitués de plusieurs mots ; on peut supposer sans erreur qu'il s'agit de la même notion pour cette locution pronominale ; il est dit dans l'article que « quoi que ce soit » s’est construit à partir du pronom indéfini « quoi ».

Answer (score 3):

The right way to write this sentence

- Y avait-il quoi que ce soit dans le rapport qui vous **ait** surpris ?

That is, the subjonctive is necessary.

However, "quoi que ce soit" is not needed for the subjunctive to be necessary; here the subjunctive results from an eventuality being considered; in other words, the subjonctive is used because that there should be something surprising in the report is only an eventuality.

- Y avait-il quelque chose dans le rapport qui vous **ait** surpris ?
- N'y avait-il rien dans le rapport qui vous **ait** surpris ?

Here is another example;

- (LBU § 377 c) S'il te demandait de faire QUOI QUE CE SOIT qui **fût** contraire aux lois du commerce,
  [...], promets-moi de ne rien signer sans me consulte.

In this exemple the same principle is true; you can replace the pronoun with a noun and the subjunctive is still necessary; this is therefore not a necessity due to the pronoun;

S'il te demandait de faire *une chose* qui **fût** contraire aux lois du commerce,
[...], promets-moi de ne rien signer sans me consulter.

The following reference will be useful in understanding the use of this pronoun;

[Emplois syntaxiques de « quoi que ce soit »](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2010-2-page-73.htm)

It can be found in it that the subjunctive is not necessary after it; here is an example from this reference;

- Il a mangé quoi que ce soit que sa mère lui **a donné**.

Answer (score 0):

- "aille" is the subjonctif present of the verb "aller" (to go)
- "a" is the indicatif present of auxilliary "avoir" that is combine to verb "surprendre" (surpris here, past participle) that is indicatif passé composé.

The correct phrase is (with subjonctif passé of verb surprendre):

> Y avait-il quoi que ce soit dans le rapport qui vous ait surpris ?